# Ruby on rails 4 app does not work in iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I embed my rails app into another website via iframe?

It works nicely with RoR 3, but not with RoR 4:

```
<iframe src="http://myrailsapp.com/" width="100%" height="50" id="rails_iframe">error!</iframe>
```

I tried to use `verify_authenticity_token` and `protect_from_forgery` options in my controller... seems it's something else (but I'm not sure).

upd. Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zP329/

Comment: Why an iframe? Is there definitely no better option e.g. use an embedded JS widget to access your site data via AJAX?

Comment: For me, a coworker was loading my application in his own, personal IFrame'd HTML page that loaded several of his daily sites and tools.  jcypret's answer was what I needed

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This has to do with Rails 4 enabling additional security protocols by default: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/25/Rails-4-0-beta1/

The setting that breaks iFrames on remote sites is X-Frame-Options. By default, this is set to SAMEORIGIN, which prevents the content from being loading cross domain:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'SAMEORIGIN'
}
```

You can read about the new default headers here:
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#default-headers

In order to allow the iFrame to work cross domain, you can change the default headers to allow X-Frame across domain.

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
}
```

Comment: After you change the configuration, your browser might still cache the old headers. You can make sure it does not, by opening your iframe in Incognito/Private Window.

Comment: "ALLOWALL" is not specified as an option for X-Frame-Options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options . Isn't it possible to remove the header?

Comment: I should also mention chrome will cache the old value, so you will need to disable the chrome cache in development.

Comment: Using a blank string instead of ALLOWALL works in Chromium and Firefox.

Comment: Is this still valid? http://ipsec.pl/web-application-security/2013/mess-x-frame-options-allowall.html

Answer (score 53):

`Rails 4` [added](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/25/Rails-4-0-beta1/) a default `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header value of `SAMEORIGIN`. This is good for security, but when you *do* want your `action` to be called in an `iframe`, you can do this:

---

### To Allow all Origins:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def iframe_action
    response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
    render_something
  end
end
```

### To Allow a Specific Origin:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def iframe_action
    response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://some-origin.com"
    render_something
  end
end
```

---

#### Use :after_filter

When you need to use more than one of your `action` in an `iframe`, it's a good idea to make a method and call it with `:after_filter`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private
  def allow_iframe
    response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
  end
end
```

Use it in your controllers like this:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :allow_iframe, only: [:basic_embed, :awesome_embed]

  def basic_embed
      render_something
  end

  def awesome_embed
      render_something
  end

  # Other Actions...
end
```

---

*Via: [Rails 4: let specific actions be embedded as iframes](http://jerodsanto.net/2013/12/rails-4-let-specific-actions-be-embedded-as-iframes/)*

Answer (score 2):

Update: seems like ALLOW-FROM and ALLOWALL are currently both invalid "X-Frame-Options" header values. The only two valid ones are DENY and SAMEORIGIN and neither allows access from another origin. See MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options.

So looks like `response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"` is the only way now to enable displaying content in an iframe on another site. But I'd love to be proven otherwise if anyone has any knowledge I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Rails 6 and Chromium 76. Previous solution with X-Frame-Options is not working. But I've noticed that it works very well when we attach online iframe with JS. So, I just made this simple solution in my view:

```html
<div id='iframe_wrapper' 'data-iframe-content'='<iframe src="https://host.com/"></iframe>'>
</div>
```

...and add JS code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wrapper = $('#iframe_wrapper')[0]
  wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.attributes['data-iframe-content'].value
})
```