# Rails Changing X-Frame-Options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, x-frame-options

Sorry for such a noob question, but I am just not figuring this out. I'm playing around with a Rails server, and for now I need to embed it in an iFrame. I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561066/ruby-on-rails-4-app-not-works-in-iframe) and  [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) *how* to change the x-frame options, but for the life of me I can't find out *where* I need to actually go to do this. I'm not sure if I need to just stick this somewhere in my app config file, my rails config file (which seems unlikely to me), but I'm obviously overlooking something.

(I don't know if this is necessary to know, but I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 4.0)

As always; thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You put it in the `config/application.rb` file. Open up the file and you should be able to see where to add it.
I'm using

`config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'})`

so that the other default headers are preserved