# Create a whitelist of sites that can iFrame mysite.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

I own a website where people create things and embed it on their website. Let's call it "mysite.com".

A user can create a page like "mysite.com/1" and embed it on their website, "acceptable.com". How can I prevent some other site like "forbidden.com" from being able to display "mysite.com/1" in an iframe?

tl;dr How can I make a "whitelist" for sites trying to iframe my own site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you can send an `X-Frame-Options` header with your server response that provides for the following options:

```
DENY
The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

SAMEORIGIN
The page can only be displayed in a frame on the same origin as the page itself.

ALLOW-FROM uri
The page can only be displayed in a frame on the specified origin.
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

To do this in rails, you can set ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19585434/1059070)) for all pages

`config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({'X-Frame-Options' => '[OPTION HERE]'})`

or for only certain pages, see [How to override X-Frame-Options for a controller or action in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18445782/1059070)