# rails 4 with iframe not working in rails 4?

Tags: iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

To work with iframe in rails4 is there any extra configuration needed to done?.

after upgrading to rails 4 iframe not working in my application which is used in so many places.
any idea on this?
i am using iframe with forms in rails4.also submiting the in jquery.

Comment: Why is not working? more info

Answer (score 4):

`Rails 4` [added](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/25/Rails-4-0-beta1/) a default `X-Frame-Options` HTTP header value of `SAMEORIGIN`. This is good for security, but when you *do* want your `action` to be called in an `iframe`, you can do this:

---

### To Allow all Origins:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def iframe_action
    response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
    render_something
  end
end
```

### To Allow a Specific Origin:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def iframe_action
    response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://some-origin.com"
    render_something
  end
end
```

---

#### Use :after_filter

When you need to use more than one of your `action` in an `iframe`, it's a good idea to make a method and call it with `:after_filter`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private
  def allow_iframe
    response.headers.delete "X-Frame-Options"
  end
end
```

Use it in your controllers like this:

```rb
class MyController < ApplicationController
  after_filter :allow_iframe, only: [:basic_embed, :awesome_embed]

  def basic_embed
      render_something
  end

  def awesome_embed
      render_something
  end

  # Other Actions...
end
```

---

*Via: [Rails 4: let specific actions be embedded as iframes](http://jerodsanto.net/2013/12/rails-4-let-specific-actions-be-embedded-as-iframes/)*

Answer (score 2):

As already answered here: [Ruby on rails 4 app does not work in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561066/ruby-on-rails-4-app-not-works-in-iframe)

There's a new default in Rails 4 which adds an header by default:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => 'SAMEORIGIN'
}
```

If you want to revert to the previous behaviour, just add the following in config/application.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'X-Frame-Options' => ''
}
```