# Embedded iFrame Showing Up Blank

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to embed this link using an iFrame: https:\bobcat-den-delivery.herokuapp.com
The iFrame is clearly there, but definitely blank.

This is my frame code:

```
<iframe src="https://bobcat-den-delivery.herokuapp.com/" style="border:2px #2980b9 none;" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" marginheight="1px" marginwidth="1px" height="300px" width="700px"></iframe>
```

This seems really simple and I am having trouble figuring out exactly what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the iFrame permissions of the site to be embedded. Adding this code to the application.rb file solved the issue:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
```

}

Source: [Ruby on rails 4 app does not work in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561066/ruby-on-rails-4-app-not-works-in-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with a normal iframe and it didn't work. The website could be blocking iframe's through .htaccess. If it's your website then look at the .htaccess.

Blocking in  .htaccess

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

But, you can enable iframes come from the same origin.

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```