# Rails/Boostrap Site Breaking a Frame

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails project with Bootstrap that is not showing up on StumbleUpon when a user stumbles onto the recommendation. I asked support and they said it was that my site was "breaking their iframe" and that it was something that needed to be fixed on my end, because the site is not allowing the page to be framed. I'm thinking this must have something to do with Bootstrap or Turbolinks, but maybe I'm completely off. Here is what's in my head tags:

```
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:title).presence || 'Title' %> | My Site</title>
  <% if yield(:meta_description).present? %><meta name="description" content="<%= yield(:meta_description) %>"><% end %>
  <% if yield(:meta_robots).present? %><meta name="robots" content="<%= yield(:meta_robots) %>"><% end %>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v1/"></script>
</head>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how is it 'breaking their iframe'?

Comment: No idea. That's all they'd tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with rails 4 additional security.  See this thorough answer for more details.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16620749/1429856